# The meaning of "factors" notation

Tags: real-analysis, notation

When I read a paper (Conjecture 2.5 of paper [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6766658)), I found a notation which is confusing,

$O(\log n~\text{factors})$.

I have no idea about the operation "factors"? What does it mean? Does it mean factorials? Many thanks!

[paper link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6766658)

Comment: It means that some $f(n)$ ( whatever they  are talking about) has $O(\log n)$ factors, which means that  if $F(f(n))$ is the number of factors of $f(n)$ then $F(f(n))=O(\log n)$ as $n\to \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to read it as $\big[O(\log n)\big]$ factors.  The number in question has that many factors within a constant multiplier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I interpret $\big[O(\log n)\big]$ factors? Does it mean the factors of $\big[O(\log n)\big]$?

Comment: No, that is the number of factors of some number. I couldn't see the link without signing in, so I don't know what number it is, but it presumably depends on $n$.  For example, $120=2^3\cdot 3 \cdot 5$ has $(3+1)\cdot 2 \cdot 2=16$ factors